# MDX Query performance issue when using DECENDANTS

Tags: mdx, olap-cube, mdx-query

I was using the below query without issues

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Value] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([Account].[Account List].[Account List].ALLMEMBERS ) } 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
 FROM [My Cube]
```

There is a requirement to get the parent of the Account (it's fixed to be 4 levels). So I re wrote it as below

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Value] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { (DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS, , LEAVES) ) } 
 DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION ON ROWS 
 FROM [My Cube]
```

Above given is a simplified version, but my ROWS is a product of around 20 Dimensions and the query using the "DESCENDANTS" wont return and times out. The query in which I don't use the descendants comes back in less than 5 seconds.

How can I achieve the desired output in a better way like in the seconds query or how do I proceed to check where is the bottle neck?

Comment: The way you’re using descendants- do you want the members of several levels to be returned?

Comment: There are ore only 4 levels to accounts dimension

Comment: You’ve chosen the slow version of descendants by using a set in the first argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing this expression:

```
Account].[Account].[Level 02].ALLMEMBERS
```

For the All member of the hierarchy, as I think DESCENDANTS will be a lot quicker if you use a member rather than a set as the first argument

Comment: I used the top level member which luckily is fixed for me always and that resolved it -> (DESCENDANTS([Account].[Account].&[-99], , LEAVES) )

Comment: Excellent I didn’t realise that descendants became recursive when used in SET mode until answering your question so thanks for the interesting question